# Show that f(A)=Det(A), where A is a matrix (nxn), is a quadratic form of fourth variables.

Tags: determinant

[image]

I tried with induction, but it doesn't works.

Comment: For $2\times 2$ matrices it works.

Comment: No, matrices n x n.

Comment: Note that $f(rA)=r^nf(A)$. This is, $f$ is homogeneous of degree $n$. Quadratic forms are homogeneous of degree $2$.

Comment: What are the variables?

Comment: Now, there is a image with the question.I do not know if it's well raised

Comment: Where it says $n$ it should say $2$. The matrix $S$ will have a $1/2$ at positions $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ and a $-1/2$ at positions $(3,4)$ and $(4,3)$.